# openxlsx how to highlight cells by comparing with another sheet

Tags: openxlsx

I want to compare two sheets values, and highlight the difference, below is a simple example, can someone help me to out about how to write the rule=? Thanks

```
wb \<- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "sheet1")
addWorksheet(wb, "sheet2")

equalStyle \<- createStyle(fontColour = "#9C0006", bgFill = "#FFC7CE")

writeData(wb, "sheet1", -5:5)
writeData(wb, "sheet1", -3:7, startCol = 2)

writeData(wb, "sheet2", 7:-3)
writeData(wb, "sheet2", 5:-5, startCol = 2)

conditionalFormatting(wb, "sheet2",
cols = 1:2,
rows = 1:11, rule = "**sheet1!A1 == sheet2!A1**", style = equalStyle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want but hopefully one of these gets what you need:

- If you want to compare cell to cell (so A1 vs A1, not A1 vs all of sheet 1),and highlight instances they're equal the rule should be `"=A1 = Sheet2!A1"`.
- If you want to compare cell to cell but highlight instances where they aren't equal the rule should be `"=A1 <> Sheet2!A1"`
- If you want to apply the style to the cell if it's anywhere in sheet 1, try [this tutorial](https://www.automateexcel.com/how-to/highlight-cell-if-value-exists-in-another-column/), whatever you would enter as the formula for the rule if you were working in excel is what gets put into the rule argument of the `conditionalFormatting`function